# how to delete grub in dual boot of windows 8 and ubuntu

Tags: grubrescue

I had installed windows 8 and ubuntu in my laptop. but after that by mistake i formatted the drive in which ubuntu was installed so now when ever i reboot my machine i get the error: unknown filesystem and grub rescue. I want to reinstall ubuntu again in the same drive but i am unable to install because of grub rescue. please suggest me solution to install ubuntu from grub rescue or to delete grub so that i can reinstall ubuntu in normal way. I am able to boot to windows if i keep the boot mode to UEFI.

Comment: You can find the solution here: [Formatted Partition and now I have Grub Rescue Error!](http://askubuntu.com/questions/387577/formatted-partition-and-now-i-have-grub-rescue-error)

Answer (score 0):

- Boot into windows and create a bootable ubuntu usbdrive through [`unetbootin`](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/).
- Then Change `UEFI mode` to `legacy mode` in bios and boot from ubuntu live usb.
- During the installation process of ubuntu select `Something Else` option.Now you can install ubuntu in a partition you want.After the installation process completed,your grub will be reinstalled.
- Now you can see both `windows` and `ubuntu` options on the grub menu.If the windows option was not displayed,then boot into ubuntu and run `sudo update-grub` command on terminal.

Comment: Why change to legacy mode? Ubuntu should be installed in UEFI mode if Windows is also booting this way. Reinstalling (in UEFI mode) as you described should work and reinstall the (UEFI) bootloader. There are probably more than one UEFI boot entries that point to wrong configurations (UUIDs). Best way would be to delete all existing Ubuntu entries before reinstalling. See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu/63613#63613

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is related to having more than one UEFI bootmenu entry for Ubuntu and the wrong one is picked leading to GRUB not being able to proceed (wrong UUID for the partition where GRUB is stored?).

I suggest booting from live media in UEFI mode and [removing the faulty *Ubuntu* bootmenu entries](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu/63613#63613) (e.g. all Ubuntu entries) before attempting to reinstall via the installer option "Something else".