# Formatted Partition and now I have Grub Rescue Error

Tags: installation, boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I done goofed.

I decided that I really didn't need Ubuntu anymore (and that I wanted to give Mint a try) so instead of doing a smart thing I went ahead and wiped the partition that Linux was running off of. Now everytime it boots it boots into the grub rescue screen.

From other readings I'm thinking that this is because my Windows boot loader was over written by Ubuntu.

My main problem is that I can't fix the boot loader (tried some command prompts from an article I read) and I can't install Win because it has to reboot during instillation and that brings me right back to the error screen!

Please help!!
Thanks!

Comment: Since you say you want to try Mint, just install it. Mint will install its own copy of GRUB and you should be able to dual-boot with Windows again.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is because you deleted the Ubuntu partition, and hence Grub's (the bootloader manager which took care of your multiboot system) configuration files. Since you've decided to use Windows OS, you'd have to restore Windows bootloader.

Here are the ways [to fix your Windows XP/Vista/7/8 bootloader](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader):

### Using Windows installation disc:

1. If you don't have a Windows installation DVD, [make your own bootable USB](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Bootable-Windows-7-or-Vista-USB-Drive).
2. [Boot with your Windows installation DVD or USB](https://craftedflash.com/info/how-boot-computer-from-usb-flash-drive).
3. Choose your regional settings, select your Location/Keyboard setting then click *next*,
4. Click on *Repair your computer*,
5. Choose the correct installation of Windows from the operating system list box and then click *next*,
6. Then in the *System Recovery Options* screen choose *Command Prompt* (Here are some [step-by-step pictures](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2880-command-prompt-boot-open-windows-10-a.html) on how to get to command prompt using a Windows 10 bootable USB.)
7. From there, type in the following 2 commands:

   ```
   bootrec /fixboot
   bootrec /fixmbr
   ```
8. Now close the two windows and click "Restart." Take out your Windows DVD and hopefully, you will be left with your Windows bootloader.

### Using [Boot-Repair disk](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/):

1. In **Advanced options** of the **[Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)** disc, choose to *Restore MBR* under the *Main options*.
2. Under *MBR options*, select the Windows 7 partition for *Partition booted by the MBR* option
3. Click the *Apply* button.

Comment: boot-repair is enough.